# Why is gfs.find() not a function?

Tags: javascript, node.js, promise, gridfs

I am trying to take [this code](https://github.com/shubhambattoo/node-js-file-upload), split it into functions across my MVC website, and make it work with my existing database and mongoose implementation. I cloned the repo and that code all works.

So far I have adapted my database connection to this:

```
const connectDB = async () => {


try {
    const conn = mongoose.connection;
    // check connection
    conn.on("error", (err) => {
      console.error(`connection error: ${err.message}`);
    });
    conn.once("open", () => {
      console.log("MongoDB Connected");
    });

    // init gfs
    let gfs;
    conn.once("open", () => {
      // init stream
      gfs = new mongoose.mongo.GridFSBucket(mongoose.connection.db, {
        bucketName: "assets",
      });
    });

    // connection
    await mongoose.connect(process.env.MONGO_URI);

    return gfs;
  } catch (err) {
    console.error(err.message);
    process.exit(1);
  }
};
```

I'm assuming it's okay to call mongoose.connect() multiple times as it returns a singleton, and won't create multiple connections. So I'm calling it in my controller to get access to my bucket, so I can call .find on it and get data out of it. Is there a better way?

The main issue is that my bucket exists in my controller file inside the gfs variable, since when I print it, it shows this:

```
[0] Promise {
[0]   GridFSBucket {
[0]     _events: [Object: null prototype] {},
[0]     _eventsCount: 0,
[0]     _maxListeners: 0,
[0]     s: {
[0]       db: [Db],
[0]       options: [Object],
[0]       _chunksCollection: [Collection],
[0]       _filesCollection: [Collection],
[0]       checkedIndexes: false,
[0]       calledOpenUploadStream: false
[0]     },
[0]     [Symbol(kCapture)]: false
[0]   }
[0] }
```

and yet when a few lines down, gfs.find() is called, an error is logged:

```
TypeError: gfs.find is not a function
```

I barely know what I'm doing, so any advice would be appreciated.

Thanks
------- update

My controller code is:

```
const gfs = require("../config/db").connectDB();

const uploadFile = (req, res) => {
  return res.json({
    message: "File uploaded successfully: " + req.file.filename,
  });
};

const getMyFilenames = async (req, res) => {
  console.log(gfs);
  try {
    const files = await gfs
      .find({
        //"metadata.uploader": req.user._id
      })
      .toArray();
    if (!files || files.length === 0) {
      return res.status(404).json({
        message: "No files available",
      });
    }
    const filenames = files.map((file) => file.filename.split("-")[1]);
    console.log(filenames);
    return res.json(filenames);
  } catch (err) {
    console.error(err);
  }
};
```

Comment: `gfs` is scoped to the block since you used `let`. But you're turning it from the function, so what about `connectDB().find()`?

Comment: gfs is also declared in my controller, as: const gfs = require("../config/db").connectDB(); ... It is within a controller function that this error is being generated. This issue seems to be caused by the promise object that is wrapping my gfs bucket. Unfortunately I'm not good with asynchronous code...

Comment: Update your post to include your controller code, as well as wherever you are calling `gfs.find()`.

Comment: Apologies. I have done so, now

Comment: God knows when `conn.once("open",callback)` calls the `callback`.

Comment: I ended up initializing my gfs bucket in my controller. It seems to be working, but I'm sure there's a better solution

Answer (score 0):

u can put gfs to global

for ex

```
let gfs

const connectDB = async () => {
  try {
    const conn = mongoose.connection;

    conn.on("error", (err) => {
      console.error(`connection error: ${err.message}`);
    });

    conn.once("open", () => {
      console.log("MongoDB Connected");
      gfs = new mongoose.mongo.GridFSBucket(mongoose.connection.db, {
        bucketName: "assets",
      });
    });

    await mongoose.connect(process.env.MONGO_URI);
  } catch (err) {
    console.error(err.message);
    process.exit(1);
  }
};

const customF = () => {
  if (!gfs) return;

  console.log(gfs)
 // gfs.find()
}

await connectDB()

setTimeout(()=>{
  customf() // it was console.log(gfs) here
}, 10000) // i think 10s is enough to connect DB
```

Comment: I'm not sure how declaring it outside of the function will allow me to access it from my controller file. Thanks though

Comment: u can do any architectury variations with global gfs and initiate gfs, so u must understand than gfs comes asynchronicaly after conn.once("open", () => ....  and inside in this cb. U can Promisificy this event model and etc

Answer (score 0):

As you saw when you printed `gfs` in the controller, `connectDB` is an `async` function which will return a promise, in this case resolving to the value of `gfs` defined in that function once it finishes executing. That TypeError is because `find` is not a method of a promise, so you need to `await` the promise first to unwrap it before calling `.find`.

There are multiple ways to do this, including:

1. Doing it inline - `(await gfs).find…` (and calling it something like gfsPromise could help make that clearer)
2. Importing the function instead, and calling it inline in place of the variable
3. Importing the function, and then initializing the variable in the controller with `await`, something like

   ```js
   const gfs = await connectDB();
   …gfs.find(…
   ```

Not knowing the libraries, I’m not sure which you would need for your purpose around singletons and such.

Also to note, but `connectDB` could return/resolve the promise after mongoose.connect resolves but before the callback in your once open handler is run, and thus resolving the promise to undefined without waiting for gfs to actually be set. So you’ll likely want to actually [construct the Promise](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Promise/Promise) to return, with the construction and resolve call lines starting something like:

```js
const gfsPromise = new Promise(…
…resolve(new mongoose.mongo…
```

Hope that helps and gives you enough to go off of/make how you would want!